# A select query involving session table in DB2 performs slow

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a temp table created in DB2 using java and then some 2000 rows inserted the same.
Now I am using this table in a select query with few joins. The query involves other 3 tables say A, B and C. Somehow this select query returns result very slow it almost takes a 20 seconds to provide results.

Below are the details of this query,

1. table A has 200000 records. B and C has only 100-200 records.
2. All these 3 tables have enough indexes defined on columns involved in join and the where clause. The Explain plan tool etc. did not show any new indexes needed.
3. When I run the query removing session table and its use in where clause, the query returns results in milliseconds. And as I mentioned this session table has only around 2000 records.
4. I have also declared indexes on each column of this session table.
5. I am not really sure about terminology here but when I say session table it is a temporary table created using db connection and the table gets dropped when the DB connection is closed. Also when the program runs with 15 threads, no thread is capable of looking at table created by other thread.

Where could the issue be? Please let me know some suggestions here.

Comment: I think if you create your temp table as a normal table with 2000 rows, your query will also take 20 seconds. But if you runstats to the table, the result may be different. Then you may get the answer from comparing those query plans.

Comment: I think we need to see the table definition, plus the query.  The explain plan would also be good.  You could be doing a Cartesian join (no conditions) which would give you a _lot_ of rows, which would likely be slow.  Indices aren't always used, depending on things like selectivity of the statement (what percentage of rows chosen), or just size of the table (small tables are loaded into memory).

Comment: Hi, I have tried one more thing. I created a table similar to the session table mentioned in above issue, then inserted same number of rows and executed the select query. The result came out in few milliseconds itself. Which means only when it is a session table involved it is taking time. Also, when I created a table I simply created it, did not define any index or did not do runstat. Definitely there is something wrong goin on with session table which I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions (I assume LUW since you don't mention platform)

a) You say that you have indexes on each column of your session table, I assume this means a set of 1 column indexes. This is in most cases not optimal, you can probably replace those with a composite index. Check what advis suggests by creating a real table like:

create table temp.t ( ... )
   insert into temp.t (...) values (...)
   runstats on temp.t with distribution

then run: db2advis -d  -m I -s "your query but with temp.t instead of session table"

b) After data is loaded and - eventually - new indexes are created, do a runstats on the session table

Comment: Hi, I have tried one more thing. I created a table similar to the session table mentioned in above issue, then inserted same number of rows and executed the select query. The result came out in few milliseconds itself. Which means only when it is a session table involved it is taking time. Also, when I created a table I simply created it, did not define any index or did not do runstat. Definitely there is something wrong goin on with session table which I am not able to understand.

Comment: Did you try db2advis?